# How to auth automatically with Google Drive Android SDK for instrumentation testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, authentication, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In order to improve app quality i'm working on testing: unit tests and UI tests. Since i'm having Google Drive support in the app with [Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) i'd like to test it and i need to auth to Google Drive account before testing (in my android app the users are able to save the files, read them, rename, etc - basic file routines).

In [auth example](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) it's shown how auth is done:

```
// 1. try connect
private void startAuthGoogleDrive() {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .addApi(Drive.API)
      .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .build();

    GoogleApiClientHolder.get().setClient(mGoogleApiClient);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

// 2. if failed - Google Drive auth intent is sent to Google Drive
// if already authorized - go to #4
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.Google_signin_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();

        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, ACTION_SIGNIN_GOOGLE_DRIVE); // sending intent to auth
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}

// 3. check result intent
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
...

// Google Drive signed in
    if (requestCode == ACTION_SIGNIN_GOOGLE_DRIVE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Google Drive does not provide token, just try to connect()
        // and get callback onConnected() instead
        GoogleApiClientHolder.get().getClient().connect();
    }

// 4. got connected callback
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
... // ready
}
```

The problems are:

1. No access token is returned (no possibility to auth another way (eg. manually in app activity) and just hardcode access token in the test
2. No possibility to auth right in the test as there is no possibility to interact with UI (Google Drive Auth activity)

What can i do in order to automate unit testing for Google Drive?

I'd like to avoid moving the tests to UI tests with Espresso and keep it in instrumentation tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create app and run it once at least to log in manually (so i have `android-library` with the code and `android-app` with app code (`src/main/java`) for manual logging and android tests (`src/androidTest/java`)). Time to time the tests will fail because of expiring token/session but in general it allows to perform automatic testing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) wherein it was noted that if you need to run your application in other environments like testing your application locally, you must detect such situation and use a different credential mechanism.

You may opt to use this:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.sqladmin.SQLAdminScopes;

// ...

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN));
```

For more information, see also [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: I'm using Android SDK and it's not pure Java SDK (your link). Updated my Q a bit